# Android - Record and Merge recorded audio files into single file

Tags: android

I am using the following code to merge two mp3 files:

```
FileInputStream fistream1 = new FileInputStream( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/My_Recording0.mp3");
            FileInputStream fistream2 = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/My_Recording1.mp3");

SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(fistream1,fistream2);

FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/My_final_Recording.mp3",true);

int temp;
while ((temp = sis.read()) != -1) {                 
        fostream.write(temp); // to write to file
}
```

But always only the first audio content gets added into my output file.
But the size of output file is increased.
I obtained these 2 input audio files by recording from MediaRecorder.
Separately the input files are playing properly. But its not getting merged together.

But the same above code works for other mp3 input files.

Can you help me how to record audio files(2 or 3) and merge them into a single .mp3 file.

Comment: you need to handle the metadata too, the so called mp3-tag and some other meta elements. Not just slap them together liken ol' sandwich.

Comment: can you give me an example